# Mongoose query for subdocument containing array of objectId's

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var groupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}},
createdBy: String,
availableModules: [Number],
members: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
```

The "members" field is just a straight up array of ObjectID's from the user table.  I need to check for the existence of a given ObjectId (user._id) in the members subdocument collection before I take some other action.

I've tried stuff like:

```
Group.find({req.body.uid}, {$in: {"members"}}, function(grps){..});
```

But this doesn't work.  I've tried a myriad of other methods but can't seem to get anything working.  I'd think this would be easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

EDIT Further Investigation:

```
User.findOne({"local.email": req.body.user.email}, function(err, user){
    Group.find({"members": user._id}, function(grps){
        if(grps){ //do something}
    });
});
```

grps is null no matter what way I do it.. tho in the mongo console it's returning the value when using the ObjectId("..") notation

```
db.groups.find({members: ObjectId("5371a4763b32c3620728acb5")})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Group.find({members: req.body.uid}, function(err, items){})
```

Comment: This was my first attempt - so I'm thinking there might be something else at play here.  It's still not working.  If I type this query in a mongo console, and use the ObjectId("......") syntax.. it returns.. so it's correct, but my type is not matching up for some reason for the equals or whatever it does internally for mongo.

Comment: I added my expanded code to the original example - have a look and let me know if I'm missing something stupid

Comment: Callback is invalid, function(err,items), not function(items). First parameter is error, second - returned array.